# Weird excution for an array loop

Tags: java

Having troubles with the exact meaning of this code

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
primes[4 - i] = primes[i];
}
```

am supposed to find the output after the execution of the code which i got a set of values.but don't understand the mechanism behind the code,don't understand the values i got.

Comment: Read the tutorial about [arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html). You can also take a paper and see which operations are performed at each iteration of the loop.

Comment: You can also print the intermediate result that will clarify what are you looking for..

Answer (score 2):

This loop is making a palindrome if your `primes` array is 5 characters long. The loop stop when `i = 2` so there are only two iterations:

```
primes[4] = primes[0];  // first iteration
primes[3] = primes[1];  // second iteration
```

For example, with the word "*Hello*", the result will be "*HeleH*". If the array is longer than 5 characters/objects, it will copy the first one in the fifth position and the second in the third position (the palindrome is just a particular case).
And of course, if `primes`'s length is less than 5, it will fails because there would be no `primes[4]`

Comment: oh ok.so if the array is 5 characters long then it will copy the first and second positions

Answer (score 0):

That loop is equivalent to this:

```
primes[4] = primes[0];
primes[3] = primes[1];
```